# Compare different objects

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I was asked this interview question recently.

Consider you have an set(K a, K b) and compare(K a, K b) interface.
eg:

```
set(A,B) means A>B
set(B,C) means B>C
set(B,D) means B>D

Now 
compare(A,B) returns '>'
compare(B,A) returns '<'
compare(A,C) returns >
compare(C,D) returns ?
```

My answer: I initially thought it represents a graph, I can build a graph and perform topological sorting, but that doesn't help.

Next approach :- Create a adjacency list using set methods.
eg:

```
A->B
B->C,D
C->E
D->F
```

logic here for compare(A,B) ..do DFS starting from A and check you can reach the goal. Eg: compare(A,C) A->B->C using DFS

Now compare(C,D) - if D cannot be reached from adjList of C, try reverse compare. Check if C is there in adjList of D, if yes then D>C, if you cannot reach goal from both ends, then return ? stating cannot find any relationship. Does this approach looks correct? Is there any better approach?

EDIT: Can we use Floyd Warshall Algo?
eg: create an extra boolean matrix and add >, < , = , ? symbol based on transitivity?

Comment: An [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) is just one way to represent a graph, so there's no benefit to describing your solution as one or the other.

Comment: Why doesn't topological sorting help? What can't it determine? Are loops allowed in the graph?

Comment: @IanMercer topological sort for above set input will give you following sequence: ABCD or ABDC , first we have to determine all possible sequences of topological sort & then go over each nd every sequence to determine its relation.

Comment: What was the interview question (or task) by the way?

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy Interview question.. i know the way as i suggested, but curious to know if there exists more efficient solution.

Comment: @Vishal Solution to which problem? You said you were given some interface. What should have you done with it? Sort some array I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that the given set relations form a graph. On closer inspection, you will realize that the graph so created is actually a *directed acyclic graph* (DAG) (as pointed out by @RalfKleberhoff in the comments). This makes examining relations (`compare`ing) much easier. For consistency, I shall assume that `set(A, B) => A > B => B is a child of A` (exactly how your adjacency list is generated).

Once we have our DAG, our `compare(X, Y)` algorithm is simply as follows:

```
compare(X, Y):
    if X is descendant of Y: // i.e. a DFS/BFS starting from Y will successfully find X
        return '<'
    if Y is descendant of X:
        return '>'
    else:
        return '?'
```

#### Explanation

Due to the way we have constructed our DAG, for a node in the DAG, all its descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) are less than (`<`) it. Similarly, all ancestors (parents, grandparents, etc.) of a node are greater than (`>`) it.

Comment: Good answer, just nitpicking: The graph isn't necessarily a tree (in the given ABCD case it is), it can be any DAG (directed acyclic graph), e.g. by adding `set(C,D)` you still have consistent compare results. But creating a cycle (e.g. `set(C,A)`) would be invalid, resulting in the contradiction of both A>C and C>A.

Comment: Great assessment, @RalfKleberhoff. I hadn't considered the possibility of a DAG. However, I think my solution should work for DAGs too. I have edited my answer to reflect the change.